# Is the MetalKit framework available for 32 bit apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, metal, metalkit

Is the MetalKit framework available for 32 bit apps on macOS? When I try to open it from a 32 bit app I receive:

> dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/MetalKit.framework/MetalKit, 1): no
>   suitable image found.  Did find:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalKit.framework/MetalKit: mach-o, but
>   wrong architecture
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalKit.framework/MetalKit: mach-o, but
>   wrong architecture
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalKit.framework/Versions/A/MetalKit:
>   mach-o, but wrong architecture
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalKit.framework/Versions/A/MetalKit:
>   mach-o, but wrong architecture

Answer (score 1):

No, Metal is a 64-bit-only framework, so it follows that MetalKit is, too.

Comment: are you sure? because seam that I can load the metal framework and I can create a MTLDevice on 32 bit. But I can't load the MetalKit framework